# How do I locally structure a frontend example from the web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using bootstrap carousel to make a website for a school project.
I want the search input box to highlight all text on the page its on so I Googled and found `mark.js` : https://markjs.io/
And I looked at the `Search bar with jump to matches` example which leads me here: https://jsfiddle.net/bap5uf8e/
So I copied and pasted the html into `index.html` added all the basic elements like `!DOCTYPE html`, `head` and `body`, copied the css into a `test.css` and referenced to it in the `<head></head>` of `index.html`.  For the JS, I cloned the repo for `mark.js` and put it in my project folder so the tree looks like this:

```
├── index.html
├── mark.js [9 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── markTest.js
├── package-lock.json
└── test.css
```

`markTest.js` is the JS code copied from the above example (link again: https://jsfiddle.net/bap5uf8e/)
Then I reference both `mark.min.js` and `markTest.js` right below the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<body>
        <script src="mark.js/dist/mark.min.js"></script>
        <script src="markTest.js"></script>
```

Next I use browser-sync (https://www.browsersync.io/) to see if the highlight functionality works but it does not.  I copied `package-lock.json` from my `home` folder to this one because it had something about `mark.js` in it and in Python which I am fairly comfortable with, I would put the `requirements.txt` or yaml file in the project folder.  It looks like this:

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": {
      "version": "3.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XwIBPqcMn57FxfT+Go5pzySnm4KWkT1Tv7gjrpT1srtf8Weynl6R273VJ5GjkRb51IzMp5nbaPjJXMWeju2MKg=="
    },
    "mark.js": {
      "version": "8.11.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mark.js/-/mark.js-8.11.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-GA8fnr74sOY45BZq1S24eb6y/8U=",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have `npm install`'ed jquery, mark.js as the above seems to indicate.  Can someone point out to me what I am missing to get this example to work locally?

Comment: If you are going to run this as a node localhost server you need a js file to run to create the server instance

Comment: @charlietfl I see, I thought I could just use browser-sync but now looking into that led me to a tutorial on gulp.

Comment: Might want to look for documented seed projects that you can simply install and run a working page from  then install your dependencies on that

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I'll start Googling what you just said :)

Comment: There are numerous node frameworks also like express, koa, hapi, sail and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
├── assets
│   ├── brand
│   └── dist
├── biosphere.html
├── clipboard.html
├── comp2680Presentation.odp
├── css
│   ├── biosphere.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── carousel.css
│   ├── dashboard.css
│   ├── famousVegans.css
│   ├── food.css
│   ├── grid.css
│   ├── mental.css
│   ├── parallax.css
│   ├── physicalHealth.css
│   ├── signin.css
│   ├── spiritual.css
│   └── starter-template.css
├── dashboard.html
├── famousVegans.html
├── food.html
├── grid.html
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── clearButton.js
│   ├── dashboard.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── mark.min.js
│   ├── nameValidator.js
│   └── navbarSearch.js
├── js_test
│   ├── basicMarkJS.css
│   ├── index2.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── mark.js
│   ├── markTest.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── test.css
├── markJsTest
│   └── index.html
├── mental.html
├── navbarSearchDemo.png
├── parallax.html
├── physicalHealth.html
├── public
│   ├── fonts
│   └── imgs
├── README.md
├── signIn.html
├── spiritual.html
└── starter.html
```

You can see my site here: https://nyck33.github.io/ecoWarriors/
The `mark.js` highlighting works.